# Rails Nested Attribute using Model Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to set up a nested model form similar to the one in Ryan Bates' Railscast Ep #196.

My models are:

```
 class EmployeeReview < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :review_ratings, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :review_ratings
  attr_accessible :employee_id


class ReviewRating < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :employee_review
 belongs_to :review_category

class ReviewCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :review_ratings
```

I've already entered in Review Categories, and I have categories separated as a model in case I want to add categories in the future.  To display all of the categories in my form, the 'new' action in my EmployeeReviews controller looks like this:

```
def new
 @title = "Employee Review"
 @review = EmployeeReview.new()
 @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
 @categories = ReviewCategory.all
  @categories.each do |category|
    @rating = @review.review_ratings.build({:review_category_id => category.id})
  end
end
```

Then I use the following code for my form:

```
<h2>Create a review for <%= @employee.first_name %> <%= @employee.last_name %></h2>

<%= form_for @review do |f| %>

<% f.fields_for :review_ratings do |builder| %>
 <b><%= builder.object.review_category.name %></b><br/>
 <%= builder.label :score, "Score" %><br/>
 <%= builder.text_field :score %><br/>
 <%= builder.label :comment, "Comment" %><br/>
 <%= builder.text_area :comment %><br/>
<% end %>
```

So the form works and displays the correct categories.  However, when I submit, it creates the review, but isn't saving the review_ratings associated with it.  Here is the code in the 'create' action of my employee_review controller.

```
def create
 @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
 @review = EmployeeReview.new(params[:review])
 @review.user_id = current_user.id
 @review.employee_id = @employee.id
 if @review.save
  redirect_to @employee, :flash => {:success => "employee review was created"}
 else
  render 'new', :flash => {:error => "Employee review was not created"}
 end
end
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but being very new to rails I can't quite figure it out, even after looking at other nested attribute posts.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Update:  Here is my schema (the sections for the models)

```
  create_table "review_categories", :force => true do |t|
   t.text     "description"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.string   "name"
  end

  create_table "review_ratings", :force => true do |t|
   t.integer  "employee_review_id"
   t.integer  "score"
   t.text     "comment"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer  "review_category_id"
  end

  create_table "employee_reviews", :force => true do |t|
   t.integer  "employee_id"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Comment: All of it looks ok. Can you post your schema. I bet you forgot a reference_id.

Comment: also, your built review ratings are showing up?

Comment: they aren't showing up, that's my problem :(

Comment: ok. Well then the builder methods are not working correctly.

Comment: posted the schema if that still helps

Comment: Your schema looks good. So let's just get the builder going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this and see if the `fields_for` actually shows up. By which I mean you actually have a review when you go to the new action.

```
def new
 @title = "Employee Review"
 @review = EmployeeReview.new()
 @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
 @categories = ReviewCategory.all
 conditions = {:review_category_id => ReviewCategory.first.id}
 @rating = @review.review_ratings.build(conditions)
end
```

First we need to see if `fields_for` is actually working and then can do you custom stuff. Let me know what happens when you swap out this code.

Comment: When I use this, my form shows the fields for only the first category.

Comment: That's because we only did one category. Submit this and see what happens. See if  `fields_for` actually saves the nested associations.

Comment: I just submitted and it didn't save the nested associations.

Comment: Here are the params that were passed: {"employee_review"=>{"review_ratings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"comment"=>"good job!",
 "score"=>"4"}}},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "authenticity_token"=>"OB4v9phdHy9McxmAB4W6nSt9vdPxhIyN0GtDBBuLJZ0=",
 "utf8"=>"✓",
 "employee_id"=>"10"}

Comment: I figured out the problem.  It was a syntax error in the create action of my controller.  Should be params[:employee_review], not params[:review].  Thanks for your help!